# Can we change source code of java in-built methods?

Tags: java

I would like to know if we can change source code of In-built methods of java, based on the requirements of the project? Can anyone let me know please

Comment: Why do you want to do so?

Comment: You can always extend classes and override methods and change/enhance its behaviour

Comment: You neither can nor should you do that: changing the implementation of built-in classes may break your dependencies in unexpected way, but more importantly, it may introduce security concerns.